# Outlook Mail add-in API works differently in the web and Outlook client

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office365api, office-js

I need to append something to the body of outlook using a [Outlook Mail add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins)

Here is how i do it

```
function getBody(cb) {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
      "html",
      { asyncContext: "This is passed to the callback" },
      function (result) {

          cb(result.value);

      });
}
function setBody(content, cb) {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(
    content,
    { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html },
    function (result2) {
        cb(result2);
    });
}
```

Here is the call

```
getBody(function (body) {
    setBody(body + " appended", function (r) {
        log(JSON.stringify(r));
    });
});
```

In the outlook web this works fine. But in the desktop client (Outlook 2016) this does not work.

This is what get for the callback result from the desktop version

```
{"value":"","status":"succeeded"}
```

This is what get for the callback result from the web version

```
{"value":null,"status":"succeeded"}
```

Please Help.

Comment: Hello,

I just tried this code in the latest version of Outlook 2016, and could not repro the problem:
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("text", function (ar) {
 var body = ar.value;
 Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(body + " appended");
});

are you still able to repro it? what build of Outlook 2016 are you running?

Comment: Hm.. There is a difference. ..getAsync("text",.. is not what i need. I need HTML formatted mail body content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, I was just appending a text to the end of a html string that is a dirty thing to do.

```
function FormatBody(bodyContent, extraContent, callback) {
    var domParser = new DOMParser();
    var parsedHtml = domParser.parseFromString(bodyContent, "text/html");

    $("body", parsedHtml).append("<div>" + extraContent + "</div>");
    var changedString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(parsedHtml);

    callback(changedString);
}
```

Parsed the html string and appended the tag i wanted. It got solved. :)

Comment: If you accept your own answer, it will be clearer to people reading this n future what the solution is